# how to validate confirm password using component in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

Here is my code of js file

```
.component("password", {
require: {ngModelCtrl: 'ngModel'},
template: '<input type="{{$ctrl.type}}" class="{{$ctrl.classname}}" placeHolder="{{$ctrl.placeholder}}" name="{{$ctrl.name}}" ng-required="{{$ctrl.ngRequired}}" ng-minlength="4" ng-maxlength="20" ng-model="$ctrl.ngModel"' +
        'ng-change="$ctrl.ngModelChange()">' +
        '<div ng-if="$ctrl.formref[$ctrl.name].$touched" ng-messages="$ctrl.formref[$ctrl.name].$error">' +
        '<div  class="alert alert-danger" ng-message="required">You did not enter Password</div>' +
        '<div  class="alert alert-danger" ng-message="minlength"> {{$ctrl.placeholder}} longer than 4 chars</div>' +
        '<div  class="alert alert-danger" ng-message="maxlength"> {{$ctrl.placeholder}} should have at most 8 characters.</div>' +
        '</div>',

bindings: {
    formref: '<',
    name: '@',
    placeholder: '@',
    classname: '@',
    type: '@',
    ngRequired: '@',
    ngModel: '<'
},
controller: function () {
    this.ngModelChange = () => {
        this.ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(this.ngModel);
    };
}
}).component("confirmPassword", {

require: {ngModelCtrl: 'ngModel'},
template: '<input type="password" class="{{$ctrl.classname}}" placeHolder=" 
{{$ctrl.placeholder}}" name="{{$ctrl.name}}" ng-model="$ctrl.ngModel"' +
        'ng-change="$ctrl.ngModelChange()" ng-pattern="$ctrl.pattern" ng- 
required="{{$ctrl.ngRequired}}"/>'+
        '<div ng-if="$ctrl.formref[$ctrl.name].$touched" ng- 
messages="$ctrl.formref[$ctrl.name].$error">' +
        '<div  class="alert alert-danger" ng-message="required" >You did not 
enter {{$ctrl.placeholder}}</div>' +
        '<div  class="alert alert-danger" ng-message="pattern" >Your 
passwords did not match</div>' +
        '</div>',

bindings: {
    formref: '<',
    name: '@',
    placeholder: '@',
    classname: '@',
    type: '@',
    ngRequired: '@',
    pattern: '=',
    ngModel: '<'
},
controller: function () {
    this.ngModelChange = () => {
        this.ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(this.ngModel);
    };
}

});
```

Here is the code of html file

```
<form name="signUp" novalidate="novalidate">
<password classname="form-control" name="Password" ng-model="pass" type="Password" placeholder="Password" formref="signUp" ng-required="true"></password>              
                 <confirm-password classname="form-control" name="confirm_password" type="password" placeholder="Comfirm Password" ng-model="confirm_password" formref="signUp" pattern="pass" ng-required="true"></confirm-password>
</form>
```

> The problem is there is no error in the input field but still it show the form.$valid property false. I spent many times on this but i found no solution.
>   I am providing my output of my code below to understand my  problem clearly

```
signUp.Password.$valid = true
signUp.confirm_password.$valid = true
signUp.Password.$error = {}
signUp.confirm_password.$error.pattern = 
signUp.confirm_password.$viewValue = qwerty
signUp.$valid = false
signUp.$error = {"pattern": 
[{"$viewValue":"qwerty","$modelValue":"qwerty","$validators":{},"$asyncValidators":{},"$parsers":[],"$formatters":[],"$viewChangeListeners":[],"$untouched":true,"$touched":false,"$pristine":true,"$dirty":false,"$valid":false,"$invalid":true,"$error":{"pattern":true},"$name":"confirm_password","$options":{}}]}
```

when i show the $error and $valid of field it show valid true and error null but in form it not same as the field's output, as you can see both gives different output. Please tell where i am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my solution

> use ng-pattern in html instead of using pattern and then use it as ng-required used in component, that's it